# Passing array from .php file to .html file

Tags: php, ajax, json

How to pass an array from .php file to .html file ?

```
   <?php 
       $arr= array(
            "first_name" => "Darian",
            "last_name" => "Brown",
            "age" => "28",
            "email" => "darianbr@example.com"
    );
   ?>
```

i have a .html file and i want to send my result from my .php file to .html file for further usage.

Comment: In the html file, use AJAX to call php file and get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML by itself doesn't do processing and can't handle arrays.

You have two options, if it's at page creation, insert a `php` snippet that takes the array and generates appropriate HTML.

If it's after the page has been drawn, use a framework like `jQuery` or `JavaScript` to get the array from the `php` file (learn about `JSON` in this case, it will facilitate the work, see documentation [here](https://www.php.net/json)) and then modify the DOM accordingly.

For example, if your script is accessed through `AJAX` (like `jQuery`), you could do something like:

```
<?php 
    $list = array( array('user_1', 1, 'continue'),
        array('user_2', 2 , '
        array('user_1', 3 , 'finish') 
    ); 
    echo json_encode($list);    
?>
```

Comment: is tat possible to carry out this transfer by this ?

xmlhttp.open("GET","myphp.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

Comment: @jc_tan yes, and you would receive the content in `xmlhttp.responseText`

Comment: emartel, may i know how can i bring a variable from <?php ?> to <script></script> ?

Comment: You probably should `json_encode` your array and then `echo` it in `PHP`. Then, in JavaScript, I strongly suggest you take a look at `jQuery` and use `getJSON` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
                
                $.getJSON('array.php', function(data) {
                       
                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.first_name + ' ' + val.last_name + ' ' + val.email + ' ' + val.age + '</li>');
                        });
                });

        });
i cant access to it, it is due to the location ?

Comment: What do you mean due to its location? is array.php accessible from your browser? you're using fields like first_name, last_name, etc... is your array associative?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include the array result in an `html` file. Both the files have to be php. You can find more info on adding them in a php file [here](http://www.terrawebdesign.com/multidimensional.php)